# vlc-qt: rtsp stream with authentication required

Tags: qt, video-streaming, rtsp, vlc-qt

I am using vlc-qt to get the video stream from a camera protected by authentication.

Doing a test with cameras unauthenticated the code works fine and the video stream is displayed correctly.

In those that require authentication instead, specifying the url as:

**rtsp://username:password@ipaddress/p1.mp4**

authentication will not be accepted.

Did I forget something or is there some other method to authenticate?

Comment: Can you open that url using VLC Player from command line (vlc <url>)?

Comment: No, once launched the command appears the authentication window even if i specify user and password in the url like above or using the command line options --rtsp-user= and --rtsp-pwd= .